# How to namespace parent props using mapState

Tags: reactjs, redux

I am told that props from the parent component are automatically passed to child, you cannot intercept them, even if you use:

```
function mapStateToProps(state: RootState,  ownProps: OwnProps) {
  return {
    s: {...state},
    o: {...ownProps},
  };
}
```

I want to make sure that props from state do not clash with props from the parent component. Is there

we are using Redux connect like:

```
export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, AllProps, RootState>(
  mapState,
  mapDispatch
)(OurComponent);
```

so for example if I have a component

```
'use strict';

import React from 'react';
import { AppDispatch } from '../../cp';
import { RootState } from '../../reducers/root';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import moment from "moment";

interface OwnProps {
  //The type for the props provided by the parent component
  s?: any;
  z1?: any,
  z2?: any,
  z3?: any,
  o?:any

}

function mapDispatch(dispatch: AppDispatch<any>) {
  return { dispatch };
}

function mapState(state: RootState, ownProps: OwnProps) {
  return {
    o: {
      ...ownProps
    },
    s: {
      ...state
    }
  };
}

type StateProps = ReturnType<typeof mapState>;
type DispatchProps = ReturnType<typeof mapDispatch>;
type AllProps = StateProps & DispatchProps & OwnProps;

class Home extends React.Component<AllProps, RootState>{
  constructor(p: AllProps) {
    super(p);
    console.log('home props:', p);
  }

  render(){
    return <div>Home Works</div>;
  }
}


export default connect<StateProps, DispatchProps, AllProps, RootState>(mapState, mapDispatch)(Home);
```

and then I render it with:

```
  <Home dispatch={null as any} s={null as any} o={null as any} z1={1} z2={2} z3={true}/>
```

I get this logged:

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is namespacing own-props separately from state-props a useful pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60556355/is-namespacing-own-props-separately-from-state-props-a-useful-pattern)

Comment: nah it doesn't really, I asked that one earlier this week - my question is also posted here: https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/issues/1540

Comment: You just don't need to `connect` the native props with the redux props, simply use it in your component would be good enough. Just didn't get the point why you want to do it. If you want a clear code view, I suppose I have given you a solution already.

Comment: I will give an upvote and let's hear others' opinions.

Comment: I don't see what the point of this is. Namespacing store values is enough to prevent clashes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only good solution is to use `mergeProps` like so:

```
interface OwnProps {
  //The type for the props provided by the parent component
}

function mergeProps(state: RootState, dispatch: Dispatch<any>, ownProps: OwnProps) {
  return {
    dispatch,
    o: ownProps,                   // ownProps are namespaced onto o.
    s: {                           // stateProps are namespaced onto s.
      apiInReach: state.dev.apiInReach,
    }
  };
}

 //// ...

export default connect(
  null,
  null,
  mergeProps
)(Dev);
```

the documentation for mergeProps is here:
https://github.com/reduxjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api/connect.md#mergeprops-stateprops-dispatchprops-ownprops--object